# invoke qml method from c++ by qquickitem as an argument

Tags: c++, qt, qml

according to [document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod), we had to send QVariant variable to a qml item function as an argument. but now we want to send a QQuickItem as an argument.
like below code :

cpp method call :

```
QQmlComponent component(engine(), QUrl("qrc:/arg.qml"));
QQuickItem *item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.create());

QMetaObject::invokeMethod( getItem("tileView"), "setTile",
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,QVariant::fromValue(0)),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,QVariant(item)));
```

arg.qml file :

```
    function setTile(tileIndex, newItem)
{
    removeContent(tileIndex)

    if(newItem !== null)
    {
        newItem.parent = root.children[tileIndex].content
        newItem.z = 1
        newItem.anchors.fill = newItem.parent

        root.children[tileIndex].addedItem = newItem
    }
    return true
}
```

is there any way to convert QQuickItem to QVariant and send them to QML items?

Comment: what about `QVariant::fromValue<QQuickItem*>(item)` ?

Comment: thank you. it's correct now.